# Delimit drawing area in Android

Tags: java, android, limit, draw, shapes

I made this application which lets the user to draw. Now, I would like to delimit it, so that the user can draw, for example, only in the center of the screen. Are there methods to set a group of coordinates as "prohibited"?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCvtL.jpg